# Laravel Auth not working in Custom helper.php file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i am not able to use Auth in global helper file and  auth is working fine in all other controller and blade file. anyone can help me regarding this issue, i searching for a solution for 3 hours can't find it what the problem.

The User Model i put all $fillable property in model

showing the error = "**Attempt to read property "role_id" on null**"

[image]

```
     <?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\AdminNavigation;
use App\Models\AdminNavigationAcess;

class MyHelper{

public static function check_access(){
    $method_name = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName();

    $role_id =  Auth::user()->role_id;
    
    $return = array();
    $return['add']=false;
    $return['edit']=false;
    $return['delete']=false;
    $return['view']=false;

    $query = AdminNavigation::select('anc.actions')->leftjoin('admin_navigation_acesses as anc', 'anc.menu_id', 'admin__navigations.id' )
                           ->where('admin__navigations.routes', 'LIKE', '%'.$method_name.'%' )
                           ->where('anc.role_id', $role_id)->get();

        if($query->count() > 0){
            foreach($query as $row){
                $getactions = $row['actions'];
                    if($getactions!=''){
                    $actionsextract = explode(',',$getactions);         
                    if (in_array(1, $actionsextract)) {
                        $return['add']=true;
                    } 
                    if (in_array(2, $actionsextract)) {
                        $return['edit']=true;
                    }
                    if (in_array(3, $actionsextract)) {
                        $return['delete']=true;
                    }
                    if (in_array(4, $actionsextract)) {
                        $return['view']=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        
        return $return;
}

}
```